# Rails: Send emails to multiple recipients with it's specific cc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, bulk-email

Is there any mailing client that supports ROR Api that allows sending bulk emails. The key is to have separate cc for each recipient.
So far I've been using Mandrill but they are closing their bulk sending service as they became part of Mailchimp.
Mailchimp doesn't support that.
I've been struggling to find any client that allows this option.

Comment: Not sure about having control over explicitly putting a recipient as a cc: for most commercial services, but you can easily do it with ActiveMailer and Gmail (read their daily limits ~2000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that due to security and anti-spam policy, most (if not all) ROR mailing clients do not support individual (specific) cc/bcc for each email in bulk sending.
At least I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is possible in 2023 thanks to ActiveMailer. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-to-multiple-recipients

> The same format can be used to set carbon copy (Cc:) and blind carbon copy (Bcc:) recipients, by using the :cc and :bcc keys respectively.

```rb
mail(
  subject: "New User Signup: #{@user.email}",
  to: [to_email1, to_email2],
  cc: [cc_email1, cc_email2],
  bcc: [bcc_email1, bcc_email2]
)
```